# Scraping dynamic forms WWW::Mechanize Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, www-mechanize

I am attempting to scrape a form and its fields from a page using the WWW::Mechanize module.

Because the main body of the webpage is created using document.write JS calls, the form methods from this module aren't finding the form I am looking for, and a call to the content method returns the page source. I need to access the resulting HTML from the document.write calls.

Is this possible using the mechanize module and if so how would I go about doing it? If not, are there other Perl modules that would help me? Thanks!

Comment: [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) supports JavaScript.

Comment: That is pretty cool, but this script would need to be run from a Linux  box that won't have the prerequisite Firefox installed with the Mozrepl plugin.

Comment: Then install it? If you're unable to install anything this task is basically impossible.

Comment: That's basically the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Also see [Do I Need An X Session To Run Firefox?](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox::FAQ#Do-I-Need-An-X-Session-To-Run-Firefox) in the `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are for the Perl solution, but you might consider Ruby.
I have done multiple web scraping scripts in both Perl and Ruby.
I found out that Ruby does a better web scraping job then Perl.

Since you are running on Linux, Ruby should be either already installed or should be a simple installation (assuming you are allowed to do installations on the server).

You can use these threeruby gems for automation:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'headless'
```

These do a very good job at web scraping.

Comment: I'm definitely open to trying different solutions. Perl just happened to be my starting point. I'll try this out. Thanks!

Comment: In order to use the headless gem, you'll need to install the Xvfb executable on you linux server in order to have a headless X server. An X server that does not require a graphics card to run, and does not actually display any graphics.  The selenium-webdriver gem will require you to install selenium on your linux server. and you'll still need to install a browser on on your linux server.  So it looks like the Ruby solution will require you to install more linux software than the Perl solution.